# Create a border around in a range for specific column criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Go through a specific column for every row and to change the border based on the values in that column and cell (Worksheets(WS).Cells(5, 3).value) to be **thicker**. Is there a way to generate an outline border around the entire range of cells used and produce the expected results?

Current

[image]

Expected Results

[image]

Your ideas/ suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your help!

```
Sub AddBorderColour(Col As Integer)
    Dim WS As String
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer

    WS = ActiveSheet.Name

    ' Find the maximum rows used in each worksheet.
    r = Worksheets(WS).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 29 To r
        If Not (Worksheets(WS).Cells(5, 3).value = "") Then
            If Worksheets(WS).Cells(i, Col + 6).value = Worksheets(WS).Cells(5, 3).value Then
                Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Color:=vbBlack, Weight:=xlThick
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you record this as a macro, it gives you a clue. What Excel is actually doing when you do this manually in Excel, is applying a top border to the top row of cells that you've selected, a right border to the right column of cells in your selction, and so on.

The code from my recorded macro is:

```
Sub border()
'
' border Macro
'

'
    Range("C3:G12").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub
```

As usual with a recorded macro, a lot of the code in there isn't actually needed, but you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro a couple of days ago, that had to "frame" certain cells/ranges.

I wrote this:

```
Sub Framer(ws As Worksheet, sAdd As String)

With ws.Range(sAdd)
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
End With

End Sub
```

And then for every cell/range we need to frame, just call this with the name of the WS that the cell/range is on, and the address of the cell/range.

In your example, the way i would do it is write a separate sub where i `Dim` 2 range references, let's say `rStart` and `rEnd`, and come up with a way to determine which cells they would refer to.
I would loop a `for` through the leftmost column that has the type of data that is of interest for this. Go from the first row to the last, and wherever the font color is black AND the font color of the cell above is red, do this:

```
For i = [whatever] to lastrow
  '[black/red], obviously you will need to find the numbers and put those here
  If Range("A" & i).font.color = [black] AND Range("A" & i-1).font.color = [red]
    Set rStart = Range("A" & i)
    Exit For
  End if
Next i
```

After this, i'd start going from the first blackfont row, looking at the "i+1"th row's font color:

```
'+100, make sure it's a number larger than the count of potential black rows in-a-row
For i = rStart.Row to rStart.Row+100
  If Range("A" & i+1).font.color = [red] then
    Set rEnd = Range("K" & i)
    Exit For
  End if
Next i
```

(Instead of doing `Do While` or `Until`, i like doing `for` loops where i overshoot with the end value and just do an `Exit for`.)
Once you have the `rStart` and the `rEnd` assigned, you just go

```
Call Framer(ws, Range(rStart, rEnd).Address)
```

Then just repeat this till the bottom of the table. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After the trial-and-error pays off, I'm glad to share the following code which can solve this question with you all.

`If Worksheets(WS).Cells(i, Col + 6).value = Worksheets(WS).Cells(i - 1, Col + 6).value Then
     Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Color:=vbBlack, Weight:=xlThick
     Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = vbBlack
     Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
 Else
     Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(i, Col).Address(), Cells(i, Col + 10).Address()).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Color:=vbBlack, Weight:=xlThick
 End If`